# Haskell Pattern Matching Problem

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

**Current Code**

Hi I have a function like this:

```haskell
jj::[Int]->[Int]
jj xs = [x|x<-xs,x `mod` 2 ==0]
```

For the **input** `[1..20]` it gives me as **output** :

```
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20] -> only the values divisible by 2
```

**What I require**

If list value is dividable by 2, it is interpreted as `0` and otherwise as `1`:

**Input** : `[243,232,243]`

**Output**  : `[1,0,1]`

Comment: You should read about the `fmap` function.

Comment: Is this homework? By the way, 244 is divisible by 2...

Comment: this is nt home work .. even this is nt what i required .. justt posted this quiz to get a simple idea how to build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely you just want map:

```haskell
jj::[Int]->[Int]
jj xs = map (`mod` 2) xs
```

Due to currying

```
map (`mod` 2) :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

is exactly the function we want, so we can just do:

```haskell
jj::[Int]->[Int]
jj = map (`mod` 2)
```

Both yield:

```haskell
*Main> jj [2,4,5,6,8,9]
[0,0,1,0,0,1]
```

Comment: One could also write `map (.&. 1)` which would be more efficient in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the [] syntax (aka. the list comprehension), you can say

```
jj::[Int]->[Int]
jj xs = [x `mod` 2 | x<-xs]
```

which is equivalent to MGwynne's `map` solution.

Comment: If one knows enough about Haskell to care about point-free solutions, I'm sure translating between the two styles of solution shoudln't be _too_ much effort!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the following functions:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
fmap :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

where a list is an instance of the typeclass functor. You'll need a function of type `Int -> Int` that does your transformation.

```
jj :: (Functor f, Integral i) => f i -> f i
jj = fmap (`mod` 2)
```

(For lists, both `map` and `fmap` do the same thing. `fmap` is a generalization of `map`)

Comment: +1 for an informative answer! It's nice to get the poster to think about such generalisations (the bread and butter of Haskell!).

Comment: `jj :: (Functor f, Integral i) => f i -> f i` works too, since you're using `fmap`.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive way:

```
dividablelist :: [Int] -> [Int]
dividablelist [] = []
dividablelist (x:xs) = mod x 2 : dividablelist xs
```